# Notify WorkerPool from ModalContext Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swt

Good day,
I'm trying to get an implementation that waits for all jobs after a UI operation to finish per a **ModalContext Thread** in which:

1. A listener for scheduled jobs is created
2. The UI operation is called in the UI Thread per Display.syncExec
3. All scheduled jobs are waited on and in case one hangs too long it's
   notified with notifyAll()

to work by calling the piece of code in the UI-Thread itself and calling my method after it so I moved the listener creation to the constructor and all's fine and dandy until we get to the notifyAll() case for jobs that are scheduled with a huge delay (WorkerPool is put in a 60 second wait()). I cannot get it to not throw an IllegalMonitorStateException.

In the previous implementation it works simply as notifyAll(). No synchronized blocks, no nothing so I expected it to work with Display.syncExec(notifyAll()) in the new implementation as the piece of code causing the jobs is run in the UIThread but it doesn't. Neither does asyncExec or running it in the ModalContext Thread. I tried a couple synchronized blocks as well but I don't see a logical reason for them considering the previous implementation.

New implementation code at this point:

```
protected void updateUI() {    
  Display display = getDisplay();
  IRunnableWithProgress op = m -> {
    //Paint
    display.syncExec(() -> display.getActiveShell().layout(true, true));
    waitUntilAllJobsHaveFinished2(display);
  };
  try {
    ModalContext.run(op, true, new NullProgressMonitor(), display);
  } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
    Log.logException("", e); //$NON-NLS-1$
  }
}

private void waitUntilAllJobsHaveFinished2(Display display) {
  Instant start = Instant.now();
  while (!scheduledJobs.isEmpty()) {
    //Avoid infinite loop from some jobs.
    if (Instant.now().minusSeconds(5).isAfter(start)) {
      display.syncExec(() -> notifyAll());
      System.out.println("---\nToSting: " + scheduledJobs + "\nSize: " + scheduledJobs.size());
      start = Instant.now();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `notifyAll()`? Use `IJobManager.join` to wait for a family of jobs to finish.

Comment: There is also `JobGroup` in newer versions of Eclipse

Comment: @greg-449 I was trying to interrupt the wait() in WorkerPool.sleep() as otherwise it waits, in my case meaninglessly, for a minute. Kinda got to it through trial and error. Will look into JobManager and JobGroup. JobManager seems to be what I need. Thank you!

Comment: The JobManager is responsible for managing the worker pool and will wake them up when they are required.

Comment: @greg-449 I'm confused. I tried `Job.getJobManager().join()` but it gets in a deadlock/hangs forever. `JobManager` is not suspended, The `Job's` status is `RUNNING`. From the JavaDoc for `IJobManager.join()` in regards to deadlocks, assuming it really is caused by owning a lock that's waited on, I think I really do need some form of `notify()/notifyAll()` but the moment I try it I get the `IllegalMonitorStateException`.

Comment: I reckon I need to sync it to `WorkerPool` since the jobs that hang go in `sleep(Math.min(hint, BEST_BEFORE))` in `WorkerPool.startJob()` triggering a `wait()` but I'm not sure I can even reach it.